# My System.out.println(); keeps printing null instead of the text it should print

Tags: java, abstract-class, subclass

I started Java a while ago and I am now busy with abstract classes. I've been busy with this code for two days now and I can't find out how to fix this. The methods names might not be in English, sorry for that but I think it wouldn't be too big of a problem.
I don't know why the output is as following: 
null null null null
null null null null
null null null null
null null null null

I hope you guys can help me out. I would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance.

Main class, which is also abstract:

```
public abstract class Boek {
public String isbn;
public String auteur;
public String paginas;
public String titel;

public abstract void setIsbn(String isbn);
public abstract void getIsbn(); 
public abstract void setAuteur(String auteur);
public abstract void getAuteur();
public abstract void setPaginas(int paginas);
public abstract void getPaginas();
public abstract void setTitel(String titel);
public abstract void getTitel();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Studieboek  sb = new Studieboek();
    Roman       ro = new Roman();
    Dichtbundel db = new Dichtbundel();

    sb.setAuteur("J.K. Rowling");
    sb.setIsbn("547896587412");
    sb.setPaginas(251);
    sb.setTitel("Harry Potter");
    sb.addNAuteur("R.K. Dale");
    sb.addOndertitel("Exactly");
    sb.printSB();

    ro.setAuteur("Suzanne Vermeer");
    ro.setIsbn("9632589632574");
    ro.setPaginas(311);
    ro.setTitel("De Zwarte Piste");
    ro.printRO();

    db.setAuteur("A.Y. Lmao");
    db.setIsbn("5781236985478");
    db.setPaginas(171);
    db.setTitel("Rijmen kreng");
db.addGedicht("Rijmpje");
    db.printDB();
}
}
```

First subclass:

```
public class Studieboek extends Boek {  
private String ondertitel;
private String nAuteur;

@Override
public void setIsbn(String isbn) {

}

@Override
public void getIsbn() {

}

@Override
public void setAuteur(String auteur) {

}

@Override
public void getAuteur() {

}

@Override
public void setPaginas(int paginas) {

}

@Override
public void getPaginas() {

}

@Override
public void setTitel(String titel) {

}

@Override
public void getTitel() {

}

public void printSB() {
    System.out.println(titel + " " + auteur + " " + paginas + " " + isbn + " " + ondertitel + " " + nAuteur);
}

public void addOndertitel(String ondertitel) {

}

public void addNAuteur(String nAuteur) {

}
```

I have two more subclasses after this but I don't think it is necessary for the code to work, because the code in both other subclasses are exactly the same and give the exact same output.

Again, any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Sincerely,

Double

Comment: Your setters aren't doing anything.

Comment: Then your tutor should probably quit teaching java. Usually a setter looks like `public void setIsbn(String isbn) { this.isbn = isbn; }`, note the part where it actually _sets_ something. Your getters are equally wrong, btw.

Comment: it's also worth nothing that what you really want is a main class with that `main()` method, with separate classes `Boek` and `Studieboek` that get instantiated in the main method. If you're starting to build out code, it's good to separate "JVM execution" from "the actual code"

Comment: @Marvin What's wrong about the getters, what should they contain? I know they should contain a return value, but the return value gives an error and whenever I leave it empty it seems fine.

Comment: @Wout I'll draw up an answer, this might require a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Your setters aren't doing anything.

A correct way to implement e.g. your setter for `isbn` would be:

```
@Override
public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
}
```

Note the part where it actually *sets* something.

Your getters are equally wrong. A getter should *return* something, i.e. not be declared as `void` and have a `return` statement:

```
@Override
public String getIsbn() {
    return this.isbn;
}
```

> I know they should contain a return value, but the return value gives an error and whenever I leave it empty it seems fine.
>   (from the comments)

I'm guessing the error is something along "a void method cannot return anything" and yes, it will be fine - unless you try something like

```
System.out.println(sb.getIsbn()); // Will also print "null"
```

I'll leave the rest up to you.

---

Bonus 1: If you have an abstract parent class anyway, you can move the common getters and setters to `Boek` instead of just declaring them as `abstract`. This will save you from having to re-implement them in each of your subclasses again.

Bonus 2: `public` fields (as in `public String isbn;`) are usually discouraged. You already have the getters and setters, so make them `protected` (see also: [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))).

Bonus 3: As already pointed out by Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans in the comments: You don't want to have your `main` method in your `Boek` class. Create a separate "application" class with only the `main` method to start up your application.

Bonus 4: I believe the standard way of what you want to achieve with your `printSB`, `printRO` and `printDB` methods would be to override the `toString()` method. Although this might be different for your special use case.

Use it as following:

```
public class Studieboek extends Boek {
    ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.isbn + " " + this.auteur; // Plus the others
    }
}
```

And

```
// No need to call an additional method, toString will be invoked automatically
System.out.println(db);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I have a lot to learn. Especially being less messy.. I appreciate it. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Your set and get methods are empty. You need to set a value in the `setters` and return the value in the `getters`.

Right now you are trying to print a variable that has not yet been set - so yes, it is going to print `null`.

```
public class FooClass{
    private String foo;

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the variable, whose values have not set. You have set the variable values in setter methods in order to print the values. Setter methods to set the values. And getter methods to return the values.

```
@Override
public void setTitel(String titel) {
     this.titel=titel;
}

@Override
public String getTitel() {
   return titel;
}
```